# How to merge two survival plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, survival-analysis

I have two plots created using `ggsurvplot` and `ggplot`.Below is the code I tried

```
p1 <- ggsurvplot(KM_new, data = data_log, time = "log_time", conf.int = FALSE)

p2 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_smooth()
```

How to merge p1 and p2 to a single plot?
I am able to get these two plots separately, but not getting in a single plot.

Comment: Hi Deepthy! Can you share the data for your plots? I can't reproduce it otherwise

Comment: Stanford heart transplant data and in p2 I had drawn the survival function of log Weibull distribution corresponding to estimated parameters. But I don't know how to club these p1 and p2

Comment: "club"??? huh??

Answer (score 6):

A `ggsurvplot` is basically a list where the survival plot is stored as an element named `plot`.

To combine your second plot with the survival plot you could add your `geom_smooth` layer to this `plot` element.

As you provided no reproducible example I draw on the default example from `?survminer::ggsurvplot`.

```r
library(survminer)
library(survival)
library(ggplot2)

fit<- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)

p <- ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung)

p$plot +
  geom_smooth()
```

[image]

And in case you want a smoothed curve for each group or strata you could do:

```r
p$plot +
  geom_smooth(aes(color = strata))
```

[image]